# Ubuntu precise, postfix, google apps - outgoing mail

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, g-suite, dkim

a n00b question from a developer, not an server admin. I'm learning - built out a linode box and have included Wordpress multisite. I have Google Apps (free) setup to handle incoming. WP sends emails via Postfix on my box. I have SPF setup so these get an SPF 'pass'. *My question* - can i get Google Apps dkim (its in my DNS settings) to work on my server-postfix-outgoing mails?

Comment: Yes you can. Go on and implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you ssmtp as MTA agent with Google Apps. Simple yet powerful. [This is how](http://wiki.debian.org/sSMTP).

Comment: It's generally considered bad form to post a short answer and a link. I'd suggest posting a description of how the SSMTP agent works with Google Apps and how to make it happen and THEN post the link.

Comment: That looks great (and ez). Ubuntu uses postfix by default (i think). The last line on the debian page (your link) says "Now just tell your MUA to run /usr/sbin/ssmtp for outgoing mails" -- can you give guidance on this piece?